# How to compute data compression ratio between redundant data structure and compressed data structure?

Tags: data-structures, compression

I recently develop a data compression algorithm, old data structure is very redundant, so I design a more appropriate data structure to store these data. For some data, performance is excellent. But now, I need to compute the specific compression ratio, I donot how to solve this? Now my answer is **serialization**, that is: store old and compressed data structure into the disk, then compare their disk space to compute compression ratio. I think it's workable, but it's a little clumsy. Is there better method?

Following is my old data structure.

```
class old{

    unsigned int _size;

    int **state_table;

    bool *is_marked;
}
```

the state_table matrix is very redundant, so I re-design data structure like this:

```
class new{

    set<StateCompression*> *state_rules;

    unsigned _size;
}

class StateCompression {

    set<int> *cur_states;

    map<int, int> *transitions;
}
```

There is another compression function that transforms the same data stored by old structure into the compressed data stored by new structure.

Can I write a count() function that computes used bytes?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By definition its the ratio of the compressed text / size of uncompressed text. How could you design a compression algorithm without knowing that?

Comment: If you have a compression algorithm, you should very easily be able to record the byte count of both compressed and uncompressed as you go. If you can only compress some in-memory data structure, I'd argue that's not really a compression algorithm, rather just storing the data in a compressed format. In that case, you can probably call the compression ratio the ratio of your representation to the in-memory representation, which would be similar to the serialized size. We'd need to know the language (and specific details) to tell you how to get the size of the in-memory structure.

Comment: Sorry, I add my old and new data structure, that will be more clear.